# how to obtain the max value in a column using VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I am interested in getting the maximum value in a column and adding a value of one. The resulting number would be stored in another column.

I have tried using the line `valuate("=MAX(AM3:AM300))")`to find the max value in the specified column but I keep getting a mismatch error, Type 13.

Could anyone please help?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim j As Long
Dim LastColumnValue As Integer
Dim NewColumnValue As Long

For j = 1 To 500
    If Cells(j, 39).Value = "" And Cells(j, 1) > 1 Then
        LastColumnValue = Evaluate("=MAX(AM3:AM300))")
        NewColumnValue = LastColumnValue + 1
        Cells(j, 39).Value = NewColumnValue
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line does this occur? Also, Dim LastColumnValue As Long

Comment: Why not use `LastColumnValue = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("AM3:AM300"))` to get the maximum value in that range ?

Comment: The seventh line is where I am looking the max value in column AM that that ranges from AM3 to AM300 @QHARR

Comment: You have 1 closing bracket too many, try `LastColumnValue = Evaluate("=MAX(AM3:AM300)")`

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the help! The extra bracket and declaring the variable using integer vs long was the problem

Comment: With that being said, I am VTC this for a typographical error. Also to the OP: I would recommend that you use the data type "Long", as it can handle much larger numbers and there really isn't a benefit by using Integer. Some people say Int uses less memory, while I've seen that Excel converts to Long in data calculations anyways

Comment: @ShaiRado is the worksheet function more efficient if working with a variable?

Comment: @QHarr I find it easier to work with, you should bench-mark it and test it. But I have a feeling the differences are something you wouldn't feel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Worksheetfunction.Max()`, and avoid infinite loops by setting `Application.EnableEvents` to `False` before changing any sheet cell and getting it back to `True` right after

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim j As Long
    Dim LastColumnValue As Long
    Dim NewColumnValue As Long
    For j = 1 To 500
        If Cells(j, 39).Value = "" And Cells(j, 1) > 1 Then
            LastColumnValue = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("AM3:AM300"))
            NewColumnValue = LastColumnValue + 1
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Cells(j, 39).Value = NewColumnValue
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```